# Divide single value into an array

Tags: php

Is it possible to divide a number into an array based on its value?

For example:

```
$val = 3;

// do something here to convert the number 3 into 1's

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

Comment: So if the value is 5, should it convert it into an array of length 5? If that's the case can't you just write a for loop?
private function toArray($value){
$toArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++)
$toArray[] = 1;
return $toArray;
}

Comment: What do you want to happen with negative numbers or zero?

Comment: It's not possible for the value to be negative, or zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = array_fill(0, $val, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array_fill(0, $val, 1);
```

will create an array

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 1
[2] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
$arr = Array();
for ($i=0;$i<$val;$i++) {
    $arr[] = 1;
}
```

But with larger numbers you may need something different.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly shorter solution is to use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
$val = 3;
$array = range(1, $val);
print_r($array);
// Output:
// Array
// (
    // [0] => 1
    // [1] => 2
    // [2] => 3
// )
```

> It's not possible for the value to be negative, or zero.

That's good, because all of these solutions (including loops) won't work with a zero or negative. However, `range()` will give you a different result (the 5 digit range of 1 to -3, for example).